# Windows 2k3 server as a KVM client

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization

Just wondering if anyone else has had issues installing Windows 2K3 server under KVM.

I have tried a few times tonight and keep getting "not a supported platform" when the installation first boots.

I've used i686, had acpi and apic off and on, given it 4GB ram, 200GB hard disk and it fails every time.

I've done some hunting around, but can't find anything conclusive on google. It is listed as a supported client on the KVM site.

Host is Ubuntu 10.04 64Bit, qemu-kmv hypervisor. Drivers, I'm not sure what your asking for there, but the disk is a standard (I believe) 32 bit Win2K3 server. I'm trying to install a bulk standard server install. I've done it with win2K8 no problems, but this 2k3 install is failing every time.

Comment: you need to provide some details on your host platform, how the guest is configured, what drivers you are using etc

Comment: well, it definitely works for me on RHEL/Fedora, so something is definitely done wrong in your case. Do you use virtio-win drivers? Or the IDE emulation instead?

Comment: To report back, I have this working now. It was the CD's my client sent me that were the problem. I downloaded the iso's from the microsoft volume licensing site (eventually, using firefox as IE wouldn't work with their site, it horrible) and the system is now installed (after 200 patches, 4 hours and 15 reboots). Thanks.